# laravel notifications - Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list'

Tags: laravel, notifications

i have an error don't know where it comes from, asking me for user_id is weird as i don't have `user_id` anywhere

Notifications table

```
Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->string('type');
    $table->morphs('notifiable');
    $table->text('data');
    $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and in the notification model i have

```
public function notifiable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

`Feedback notification`

```
/**
 * @var \App\Models\Feedback
 */
protected $feedback;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @param \App\Models\Feedback $feedback
 */
public function __construct(Feedback $feedback)
{
    $this->feedback = $feedback;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param mixed $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param mixed $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'title' => $this->feedback->title,
        'message' => $this->feedback->message,
    ];
}
```

Error message

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `notifications` (`id`, `type`, `data`, `read_at`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved. i made a dummy mistake by adding `notifications` function in user model while i don't need to after using `notifiable` trait

works fine now